# How do I enable auto login on gnome shell 3.18.5?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I didn't unity so I installed gnome shell 3.18.5 on my ubuntu 16.04. Now every time I start my laptop I have to enter password to login. Auto login is enabled in settings but doesn't work for some reason. So how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps autologin for Gnome Shell only works wiht GMD display manager, whereas you may (still) be using lightdm, the default display manager of 16.04.

Comment: How do I change the display manager to lightdm?